# How to keep mounted in 2 component working same time in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I use `window.onresize` in `mounted` in 2 different component. When the window change the size, it will run the code in `window.onresize` but it only run 1 component, not 2 component the same time.

How can I make it run both `window.onresize` in 2 component a same time?

```
mounted() {
  window.onresize = () => {
    this.productDetailRatio = window.innerWidth / 1900;
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.productDetailRatiofont =
      window.innerWidth / 1900 < 0.5 ? 0.5 : window.innerWidth / 1900;
  };
}
```

I use this in 2 different components and I want it both run in 2 components when i change the window size but it only work 1 component.

Comment: use store - for example vuex

Comment: @EmīlsGulbis can you explain more detail? I have just learned vuejs.

Comment: please provide a minimal example thanks

Comment: @DenisTsoi I have some code, please check it

Answer (score 0):

I mean its wrong tactic.
MDN writes:

> The onresize property of the **GlobalEventHandlers** interface is an
> EventHandler that processes resize events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

So when your second component has been mounted - `window.onresize` was rewritten

If you want to change something in a component when window be resized you can use "watch" methods https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

You need create a global variable like windowSize, when window was resized assign new size to windowSize, and in component watch windowsSize